# Convert date as Integer in Codebehind

Tags: asp.net, date, integer, code-behind, raddatepicker

I've been searching around the net but I only see integer to date. How can I convert a chosen date in radDatePicker to integer? I have tried Convert.ToInt32 but I get an error at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
  DateTime dt =Convert.ToDateTime(RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate);
  string  temp = dt.ToShortDateString();

  int value;
  int.TryParse(temp, out value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks
```

For normal datetime object it works. Means if you could get DateTime value from radDatePicker you may apply `.Ticks` property to it.